# Can't seem to simulate click event with jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm new to testing using Jest and need to simulate a click event. I have been able to select the element with enzyme css selectors and trigger the event but the test is still failing saying I haven't run the function.

```
Test: 


it('test',() => {
  const e = { target: {id:'X'} }
  const click = jest.fn();

  let wrapper = shallow(<GameBoard onClick={click}/>);
  let test = wrapper.find("#gameBoard").childAt(0)
  test.simulate('click',e)
  expect(click).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)

})

Component :

import React, {Component} from 'react'


class GameBoard extends Component {

  handleClick = (e) => {
  this.props.turn

    if (e.target.innerText === ''){
        this.props.addToTotalMoves()
        e.target.innerText = this.props.turn

        this.props.updateActiveBoardArray(e.target.id)

        this.props.changeTurn()
      }
    }
  render(){
    return (

        <div id ='gameBoard'>
          <div
          id = '0'
          className = 'boardTile'
          onClick = {this.handleClick}
          ></div>
```

Comment: Did you bind the onClick handler?

Answer (score 2):

looking at source of `GameBoard`'s `handleClick` we can see it does not call `this.props.onClick()`.

Instead it calls

```
    this.props.updateActiveBoardArray(e.target.id)
    this.props.changeTurn()
```

So you have to pass those `props` in your test and check if they are called:

```
const e = { target: {id:'X'} }
const updateActiveBoardArray = jest.fn();
const changeTurn= jest.fn();

let wrapper = shallow(<GameBoard 
    updateActiveBoardArray={updateActiveBoardArray}
    changeTurn={changeTurn}
/>);
let test = wrapper.find("#gameBoard").childAt(0).simulate('click', e);
expect(updateActiveBoardArray).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
expect(updateActiveBoardArray).toHaveBeenCalledWith('X');
expect(changeTurn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```